# Creating Automation to Create Multiple Columns in between a Data Frame

Tags: python, list, dataframe, automation, keyerror

I am new to coding in this aspect and need help creating x amount of columns. I have a datagram that currently being updated and I need a way to show that whatever columns from the data frame the user picks it will show just those selected columns but in-between those columns I want a column to say 'Keep'. So far I was able to have the code select what the user wants, I am just having trouble creating a automated way to make the keep show up without adding them myself in between.

```
 name_of_cols =['id','start_date', 'end_date', 'name', 'job_title', 'Keep']
```

All but Keep is part of the data frame prior.

```
def clean_df(df, list_col):

  df2 = df.copy()
  df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(list_col)
  df3 = df2.copy()
  df3 = df3[[id,start_date, end_date, name, job_title]].reset_index(drop = true)
  df_3 = df3_new.columns.tolist()
  conditions =[df3 = name_of_cols,
  df3!= name_of_cols
  results = ['Keep' , 'No Keep']
  df3_new['Keep'] = np.select(conditions, results)
 return df3[name_of_cols]
```

---

```
df3_new = cleanup_df(df3, name_of_cols)
```

This creates the list I need but when I try and add 'Keep' I get:

```
  KeyError: Index([Keep'], dtype='object')
```

I am assuming this is because 'Keep is not apart of the orginal data frame.

I have code that defines all this so defining the data frames are not an issue I have.

Comment: Please double check for typos. For example, you write `df3_new['keep']` but you want to read `KeyError: Index([Keep'], dtype='object')`. Also, maybe a lost `'` quotation mark?

Comment: Thank you sometimes I look over spelling typos, but that did not resolve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, as far as your code goes, it might be a syntactical error.
  `results = ['Keep' , 'Don't Keep'] df3_new['keep'] = np.select(conditions, results) return df3[name_of_cols]`
It seems like you have an unintended apostrophe where you have `Don't Keep`. I might suggest using quotation marks to eliminate this issue, but I don't know if this is the solution you are looking for. (I don't know a whole lot about data frames)

Comment: I just changed the result to equal 'No Keep', this part isn't really important because hopefully at the end everything should be Keep regardless.